# Why is the size of update manager different from time to time?

Tags: 12.04, installation, update-manager

At the first time, I installed ubuntu 12.04 on my desktop and ran the update manager. At that time, the size of the update is about 168 MB. Then I did something wrong on device installation, so I decided to re-install ubuntu by erasing the previous one. But what I noticed was that when I ran the update manager on the new ubuntu, the total size of the update is now about 100MB, not 168MB. So now I am wondering if there's something broken on the last installation, because the size of the update is smaller than the previous one's...
Please tell me whether this is a fault at installation or I can ignore this and proceed

Thank you

=====================================================================

OK. This is not a fault. I did three installations on the same machine, all without internet connection, and then later ran the update manager. Then the size of the update was identical for every installation. It looks like sometimes, updates during installation from internet differ from time to time, but as a whole, there is nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably there was broken update that included unnecessary data files. Without more information, it's hard to know what exactly happened.

For example, maintainer could have pushed update for graphics files (say, background images) that only included some trivial changes. Later that was reverted.

Or on the second time, your Ubuntu automatically downloaded part of the update, and thus showed only 100MB for download size.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. After posting this question, I re-installed ubuntu 12.04 again, and this time the size of the update is 210MB. And I checked the installation media and no error was found. Now I am confused.

Comment: Me too. Did you choose exactly same packages during the installation? I guess you're reinstalling it on the same computer? (There's hardware-specific packages too)

Comment: Yes. I chose exact same configuration on the same machine. I think I will just ignore this and proceed. If something's wrong in the future, then I will find ways to solve issues.

Comment: In *theory* it could download data from different mirrors and thus get different versions of packages, if mirror sync is not finished. That's the best explanation I can come up with. Unless you manually choose the mirror, it's automatically chosen by your location, and then randomly picked from list of closest mirrors.

Comment: It seems most likely that you've got some form of automatic updates going on downloading the packages in the background (and you're opening it at different points in time). I wouldn't worry until something actually breaks.

Comment: Well... I'm in South Korean but I chose Japan because strangely Korean mirrors are slower than Japan's. But I chose this option consistently in every installation so I don't think mirror is issue.

Comment: Yeah. I will just proceed. Anyway, thank you for your help.